# Result showing [object Object], [object Object] in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click a delete button, a prompt will come up. The prompt works well but somehow it is displaying a weird [object Object], [object Object]. I want it to be such that, when the prompt comes up it refers to the `name` in the object. For example, when I click the delete button, the prompt will come up on browser like this,

`Do you want to delete jabss ?`

But now it is showing,

`Do you want to delete [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ?`

Here is the delete function button logic and where it is used in the code. How can I fix this ?

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const newPerson = persons.filter((person) => person.id !== id)

    if (window.confirm(`Do you want to delete ${newPerson} ?`)) {
      personService
        .delete(id)
        setPersons(newPerson)
    }
  }
```

It is used below in the `Person` component,

```
    <ul>
          {persons.filter((person) => {
            if (searchTerm === "") {
            return person
          } else if (person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
            return person
          }
          }).map((person, id) => {
            return (
            <Person key={person.id} person={person}  deleteButton={()=>handleDelete(person.id)} text='Delete' />
          );
          })
          }
   </ul>
```

db.json where the data is stored,

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Arto Hellas",
      "number": "040-123456",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "number": "39-44-5323523",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "jabss",
      "number": "21321312321",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "kamal",
      "number": "231321321321",
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "jabri juhinin",
      "number": "321321321321",
      "id": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `const newPerson = persons.filter((person) => person.id !== id)` I think you want to make this `person.id === id`

Comment: Have you tried with `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo what do you mean Json.stringify() ? you Json.stringify(newPerson) ?

Comment: after the above fix is done, you should probably use `.find` instead of `.filter` to give you one result, not an array, and then change this

Comment: ``Do you want to delete ${newPerson} ?`` to this ``Do you want to delete ${newPerson.name} ?``

Comment: @TKoL I tried that but it still gives an error, 'Do you want to delete undefined ?'

Comment: well either that id doesn't exist in your persons array, or you're having a type issue. try using `==` instead of `===` for the type issue - the id may be a number instead of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `find` method to return just single record instead of `filter` method which returns `array`, then get the `name` property.

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const newPersons = persons.filter((person) => person.id !== id)
    const newPersonName = newPersons?.[0]?.name
    if (newPersonName && window.confirm(`Do you want to delete ${newPersonName} ?`)) {
      personService
        .delete(id)
        setPersons(newPersons)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please check setPerson called in the end. This will remove all the persons data saved in react state.

Comment: I dont think this is gonna work. I still want the filter method to work because it is related to deleting the data. If I were to follow the code above, it would solely only work in this particular situation but affect the delete functionality

Comment: @JabriJuhinin CodeThing, Sorry I didn't notice that, I just update the answer, please review.

Comment: this works but the ${newPerson} in the code has to change to ${newPersonName}..but I don't really understand what the code in const newPersonName = newPersons?.[0]?.name . can you explain in words how is the code flow in newPersons?.[0]?.name ?

Comment: @JabriJuhinin, Yes sorry I update it, about `newPersons?.[0]?.name`, it means to check if `newPersons` is not `undefined` then get the first item in it `[0]` and check if the first item not `undefined` get the `name` property, I just realized you don't need first check because `newPersons` will never be `undefined` so you can use `newPersons[0]?.name` directly. for more resources [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: never did optional chaining before, thanks ! i think it is a very useful method to get object's property and will be use in a lot of situations

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: fix the filter logic

`const newPerson = persons.filter((person) => person.id !== id)` should be `const newPerson = persons.filter((person) => person.id === id)`.

Step 2: use find and not filter, to get 1 result and not an array of results.

```
const newPerson = persons.find((person) => person.id === id)
```

step 3: display the persons name, not the entire person object, in your string.

```
if (window.confirm(`Do you want to delete ${newPerson.name} ?`)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
const newPersons = persons.filter((person) => person.id !== id);
const personToDelete = persons.find((person) => person.id === id);

if (window.confirm(`Do you want to delete ${personToDelete.name} ?`)) {
  personService
    .delete(id)
    setPersons(newPersons)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save the person to delete temporary all at once without doing a separate `.find` or an extra `.filter`

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    let personToDelete;
    const newPersons = persons.filter((person) => {
     if (person.id === id) {
       personToDelete = person;
       return false; // return is not necessary but looks cooler
     }
     return person.id !== id
    })

    if (window.confirm(`Do you want to delete ${personToDelete.name} ?`)) {
      personService
        .delete(id)
        setPersons(newPersons)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think. there's no need to find deletedPerson again.
You can simply pass Person object as a parameter.

```
<Person key={person.id} person={person}  deleteButton={()=>handleDelete(person)} text='Delete' />

const handleDelete = (person) => {
const newPerson = persons.filter((person) => person.id !== id)
if (window.confirm(`Do you want to delete ${person.name} ?`)) {
  personService
    .delete(person.id)
    setPersons(newPerson )
}
```

}